# How to export database with some options in a script?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have written a script to do regular exports of  my database :

```
#!/bin/bash

current_date=`date '+%F-%H-%M-%S'`

cd /home/user/Documents/backup
mysqldump -umyusername -pmypassword mydb > db-backup-$current_date.sql
tar czvf db-backup-$current_date.tgz db-backup-$current_date.sql
rm db-backup-$current_date.sql
```

but I would like to export it with the following options available with phpMyAdmin :

- Enclose export in a transaction
- Disable foreign key checks
- Add DROP TABLE / VIEW / PROCEDURE / FUNCTION / EVENT statement

How I can do that ?

**EDIT**

I can add the following lines at the beginning of mydatabase.sql file ?

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET AUTOCOMMIT=0;
START TRANSACTION;
```

If it is right to do that, so I guess my problem is how to insert lines in a given position ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can probably do most of it through mysqldump itself:

```
mysqldump \
--user=LOGIN \
--password=PASSWORD \
--single-transaction \
--events \
--triggers \
--routines \
--disable-keys \
--create-options \
database  > dumpfile.sql
```

The `--create-options` should issue the `drop` command too.

Have a look at `mysqldump --help` for a list of all possible options

An alternative is to look in the PHP for `phpMyAdmin` and see what options it uses